# Text colliding the social media icons

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create something like this:

[image]

Where the border is collding with the social icons.

What I did so far is create a div like this:

```
  <div class="social d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <div class="social-item"><a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook"></a></div>
                    <div class="social-item"><a href="#"  class="fab fa-twitter"></a></div>
                    <div class="social-item"><a href="#"  class="fab fa-google-plus"></a></div>
                    <div class="social-item"><a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="border-social"></div>
```

Then on my CSS:

```
.social{
    width: 60%; 
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.border-social{
    border: 2px solid black; 
    margin-top: -13px; z-index: 0;
}
```

But this did not work. How can I achieve that using my code?

Comment: The code you have shown does not even come close to reproducing what your screenshot shows. Provide a _proper_ [mre] of what you have so far, please.

Comment: His code is fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Your z-index is not working because it only works when you also have the `position` attribute.

This will fix it. ;)

```css
.social {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

.border-social {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: -13px;
  z-index: 0;
  
}
```

result:
[image]

(sorry, I couln't find the right sylesheet to show the icons, so you'll have to deal with looking at these squares)

Answer (score 0):

No need for another DOM element (i.e. `border-social`).
You can do it with pseudo-elements.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tozajfwm/1/).

```
.social {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  height: 15px;
}

.social-item {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.social::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Result:

[image]